# SSRS 2008R2 Report Parameter not working

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Report with a Stored Procedure data source. That takes 'A', 'B', or 'F' See below

```
SELECT CAST(HT_Mail_Date AS DATE) as HT_Mail_Date,
       HT_RecType,      
       CASE STC_SCAN
          WHEN 'Yes' THEN 'STC Scan'
          WHEN 'No' THEN 'Non-STC Scan'
          ELSE 'No Scan'
       END AS Scan_Type,
          COUNT(HT_serNum) AS Mail_Pieces
       FROM CT2_Mail_data LEFT JOIN CT2_Trace_Data ON HT_SerNUm = TR_SerNum
       WHERE HT_RecType = @SvcType
          OR @SvcType = 'A'
       GROUP BY HT_Mail_Date, STC_SCAN, HT_RecType
```

When I go to SSMS and run the stored procedure giving it a valid parameter it works fine. I can click of the data source in BIDS and open the query Designer and give it a correct PARAM it works. When I open the Preview and select or default it to a valid PARAM it returns "No Data available". 
[Screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpRKG.jpg)

Comment: Is the dataset query type set to "stored procedure" or "text"? Also in the dataset properties, Parameters tab, what is selected in the value column?

Comment: You should post the full stored procedure definition. Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the start? Does it work as expected when you just plug that SQL straight in?

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone. I was able to get it working by deleting the reports and reading them. something was out of sync I presume. Next time I will post the full Stored procedure. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was able to figure this one out by myself. What I had done was created shared datasets with the same name for three different reports. The issue became clear when I realized the values in one dataset reflected the values specified in a different report. The solution was to rename the datasets CT1_Dataset1, CT2_Dataset1,CT1_Dataset2, CT2_Dataset2...